# How to make Nike+ Connect software work in Ubuntu. (Nike GPS Watch)

Tags: wine, software-installation

I am owner of nike+ GPS watch and unfortunately, [software (Nike+ Connect)](http://nikeplus.nike.com/plus/setup) for uploading my running data to Nike+ webpage is made just for Mac and Windows, I tried to install it on Wine but it seems as the software can´t detect my watch which in the USB port. Can somebody help me with this problem please?

Comment: i am not sure if it help you but check this article [Ubuntu Runner's Guide: Using Garmin Forerunner & Nike+ with Ubuntu](http://www.muktware.com/articles/640/ubuntu-runners-guide-using-garmin-forerunner-nike-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this one but unfortunately it is 2 years old and not working anymore...